# C++ - Memory pool in game engines and object allocation

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I'm making a small game engine and need to have a memory pool associated with it. 
My question is, how do I actually share that memory to users who got their own classes?

For example, I have a user who got this class in his game;

```
class Monkey : public GameObject {
public:
    Monkey();
    ~Monkey();

    void Eat();
    void Sleep();

    unsigned long size();

private:
    int health;
};
```

I got a baseclass which, at the moment, just returns the size of the derived class. I figured this would be needed to know how much space this would occupy in the pool.

```
public GameObject {
public:
    virtual unsigned long size()=0;
};
```

And he wants to allocate a new instance of this class in my memory pool.
I do not know the class definition at compile time,so I just can't figure out how the actual method call would look like. He cannot pass me an object inheriting from GameObject, because that means he already has allocated it, which defeats the purpose of pre-allocated memory pool. So how does the reserving of memory actually work for any arbitary class instance?

Sorry if its unclear

Comment: First, this belongs over on [gamedev.se](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). Second, why do you need to have user-derived objects allocated in a memory pool?

Comment: Memory pools allocate fixed-size blocks, I don't get why you need the size, as it's constant.

Comment: Not necessarily game-related though, more general on memory-pools, game engine is an example. The reason to have the allocate the users objects in a memory pool, as I imagine, is so avoid having to allocate it on the heap which would take time to allocate/deallocate, no? In real-time apps a memory pool with fast allocation sounds good

Comment: The memory pool is a fixed size, but the objects that are to be fitted in the pool should be able to vary in size, otherwise I can only allocate one type of object in the pool right?

Comment: @KaiserJohaan: "sounds good"? You don't do something like this because it "sounds good". You do it because you have a *known* performance problem (either from profiling or experience), and memory pools will fix it. Otherwise, it's just a premature optimization.

Comment: My question is: Why are you trying to use memory pools for this particular style of class?  C++ doesn't have GC built-in and you're probably not using it, so you won't ever see a GC hitch, so you can feel free to do heap allocations as long as you're not killing your CPU/memory budget with them.  Game entities are usually long-lived (many frames), and many game engines update them at a lower frequency than physics and graphics (10/s instead of 30-60/s).  Most game engines separate loading and unloading art assets from game entity creation/destruction, and many pre-cache at level load.

Comment: Where memory pools are most useful is in reducing cases of known constant allocation churn of homogeneous objects.  Usually this is in the physics/graphics portion of the game engine, as it has the highest update frequency.  Physics objects tend to be relatively homogeneous, so they're easier to pool.  Meta-graphics objects (not 3d or 2d assets) are probably easy to pool, such as individual particles in a particle system or instances of weapon fire (also basically particle effects).  As Nicol said, don't optimize prematurely :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Memory pools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool) only allow allocations of a fixed size. Therefore, if you're trying to allocate variable size objects with one, then the fixed size of the allocation is the maximum size you can allocate.

If you want to overload the allocation behavior, you need to overload `operator new/delete` on your base class. It should `throw std::bad_alloc` if the user attempts to allocate a type beyond the max size of the memory pool. Also, you should overload `operator new[]/delete[]` to just `throw std::bad_alloc`, since allocating arrays of these will probably not be a good idea.

The overloaded `operator new/delete` will be given the proper size of the type it is allocating. All derived classes will inherit the overloaded operators... unless the user overrides it. And if they do... smack them.

The overloading itself is simple:

```
public GameObject {
public:
    void *operator new(size_t size);
    void operator delete(void *memory);
};
```

You will implement those by calling your pool to fetch a block of memory, or to deallocate the block of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Your memory pool will provide an API for allocating memory and you'll either implement `operator new` static member functions that use your pool for the base class, or make clients use placement new to construct any objects they want in memory allocated in your pool.

In the first case allocation and destruction will be exactly as normal, because the standard `new` operator and `delete` operator will end up calling your custom `operator new` and `operator delete`. So it should be completely transparent to your clients. However only objects in that inheritance heirarchy will be able to be allocated in your pool.

The second method will be slightly different because it will require the participation of clients. Either they have to allocate/free memory and construct/destroy objects manually (which is difficult and unsafe), or they'll use smart pointers with a custom deleter that destroys the object and frees the memory. With this method the client can put anything they want in your pool, including types that don't inherit from anything, such a large array of doubles.

Answer (score 0):

Have your pool act like malloc. Construct the objects outside of the pool using placement new:

```
object1* x = new (alloc()) object1();
object2* y = new (alloc()) object2();

x->~object1(); free(x);
y->~object2(); free(y);

// this can (and should) be wrapped in functions, such as operator new/delete
```

There are much better ways to do this, but this will work with the pool not knowing the declaration of your classes.

Comment: Note that if `object1` or `object2` are too large for the pool, this will cause all manor of badness.

Comment: @NicolBolas Added the parens. And yeah, client should make sure the objects are small enough.

Answer (score 0):

**KaiserJohann**, what you seem to be specifying is a system that allows dynamic allocation for variable sized elements. That is pretty much a request for a dynamic allocator.

Here is my article on [Dynamic/Pool Hybrid Allocation](http://jsperfunkn0wn.blogspot.com/2011/12/dynamic-allocation-with-pool-benefits.html), which should help you with your situation.